# Are prime ideals always comaximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is easy to see in the ring of integers. In fact, the ideals don't even have to be prime. It's enough to be coprime. Then their GCD is 1, so 1 can be written as a linear combination of the generators of your ideals, and once you get 1 in the ring, you have the whole ring.

Is this true for rings in general? If not, what conditions must we impose on the ring (euclidean domain, principal ideal domain, etc.) in order to make it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the prime ideals $(X)$ and $(Y)$ in $K[X,Y]$?

A class of rings where happens what you want is that of [Bezout domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain). (PIDs are Bezout domains.)

Comment: It's not immediate from the definition of Bezout domains that prime ideals are comaximal.

Comment: @ZachGershkoff Maybe I didn't get your question: if you are looking for rings with the property that any two distinct prime ideals are comaximal then these are all maximal (otherwise take a non-maximal prime and a maximal ideal containing it), so we are talking about *rings of Krull dimension zero*. But if you look for integral domains where any two distinct prime elements are comaximal, then the *Bezout domains* are the right choice.